# Error: 'items must have at least two valid response categories with 5 or more cases.' when I already have 2 catagories

Tags: r

I am doing a DIF analysis on R using lordif package. I have 20+ graded variables and 2 categorical variables. Each categorical variable has 2 categories. 
Error message ""items must have at least two valid response categories with 5 or more cases.
but i had at least 2 valid response categories with 5 or more cases.

I tried: 
1. adjust the format of cells of the categorical variables to "numerical"

```
bmiDIF1 <- lordif(D1, bmi, criterion = c("Chisqr","R2","Beta"), alpha = 0.01,  minCell=5)
```

Error in collapse(resp.data[, selection[i]], group, minCell) : 
  items must have at least two valid response categories with 5 or more cases.

I then tried to revise the code:

```
bmiDIF1 <- lordif(D1, bmi, criterion = c("Chisqr","R2","Beta"), alpha = 0.01,  minCell=1)
```

The new error message is 
"Iteration: 36, Log-Lik: -1054.273, Max-Change: 0.00006
ERROR: The following items had negative slope parameters.
1,2ERROR: The following items had negative slope parameters (1,2)."

Comment: The first error message means that there is atleast one BMI category where there are less than 5 cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years late, but just to help someone who might be struggling in future. In my case, I got this error message where I did still had groups that should not have been there. I had one case for group 6 which should have been removed with the rest of group 6. After removing the one record the analyses ran fine.